# Observable .next() to specific Observer

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs, observable, observers

In my Angular 2 app, I have a communication service that I use for broadcasting message over others angular component.

```
@Injectable()
export class CommunicationService {
    private _broadcast = new Subject<EventParam>();

    broadcast$ = this._broadcast.asObservable();

    public sendEvent(eventParameters: EventParam): void {
        this._broadcast.next(eventParameters); 
    }
}
```

This works well, but sometimes I know to which component I want to send my message : it's possible with RxJs to send message to a specific observer ?

Comment: Do you mean a "specific subscriber"?

Answer (score 1):

`Observables` are meant to be decoupled from `Observers`, so there isn't a way to really do this by a named look up if that is what you are hoping for. That being said, you can use a `filter` to do an optional filtering operation.

```
//In a consumer of your service
communicationService.broadcast$
  //Will allow through events based on an optional field
  .filter(({name}) => !name || name === 'component1')
  .subscribe(x => /**/);
```

Comment: Observables are meant to be decoupled from Observers. what does that mean? Can you please explain?

Comment: @YashwardhanPauranik I think the author of this answer means that the `Observables` (information eligible to be listened too) should *not* know how its information is listened too by the `Observers` (the listeners in your implementation). So in this sense, your `Observers` should decide what information it should care about, hence the filtering.